# How can I modify data from timestamps to consumption per day per user?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, ms-access

For my Bachelor Degree in Economics I need to analyse data on energy consumption. However, I got some data set delivered in a certain format and I have troubles with modifying this data to make it useful for me and to be able to analyze it with Stata.

I have some basic skills in Python and SQL, however so far I didn't succeeded with my last data-set for my thesis. I would be grateful for all your help :)

The problem:
I got a data-set with 3 columns and 23 million rows. The 3 columns are time-stamp, user(around 130 users) and consumption(Watt per second).

[Example of data set in Access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9o9Z.jpg)

On the first example, you can see that some users have negative consumption.

Those users are irrelevant for my research and all users with negative consumption values can be removed. How can I easily do this?

In the second example the raw data-set is given. The time stamps are based on intervals around 10-15 seconds and are consecutive. So measurement 1458185209 is 10-15 seconds after measurement with time-stamp 1458185109. Those time-stamps are anonymously generated. However,I know the exact begin- and end-time and date of measurements.

From this information, I want to calculate the average consumption (In KWatt/hour) per user per day. Let's say, there are 300.000 measurement points per user in the data-set. The total time of measuring is 2 months. So the average consumption of a user can be calculated by taking the average from time-stamp 1 till time-stamp 4918 (300.000/61 days).

I want to do this for all users for all days in the given period.

I have some basics in Acces, Python and MySQL. However, all computers I tried on have troubles with 23 million rows in Access. In Access I simply can't 'play' with it because every iteration takes me about half an hour. Maybe the option could be to write a python script?

As said, I am a student in economics and not in Data Science so I really hope you can help me trying to overcome this problem. I am open for any suggestions! I tried to describe the problem as specific as possible, if there is something unclear please let me know :)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: MS Access is so not the right database for this.  Stack Overflow is not for recommendations, but I will mention Postgres, SQL Server Express, BigQuery (trial) as free solutions that offer better capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any indexes defined on your dataset? Put an index on user, timestamp, and both user and timestamp could greatly improve performance of some of your queries.

When working with the much data it will likely be best to offset as many calculations to the database as you can and only pull the already processed stuff into Python for further analysis.